# Optimal Hierarchical clustering for documents in WEKA/ JAVA

Tags: weka, hierarchical-clustering

The problem is following :

Input Data : 1000 text files

So for this Data I want to apply the optimal Hierarchical clustering using WEKA/ JAVA. As, we know in hierarchical clustering eventually we will end up with 1 cluster unless we specify some stopping criteria. Here, the stopping criteria or optimal condition means I will stop the merging of the hierarchy when the SSE(Squared Sum of Error) is MAX. When it stops it should return the number of the clusters.

I have searched WEKA but all I found so far is - it supports the hierarchical clustering but I did not find how to set the stopping criteria OR how to get the optical numbers of clusters.

Is there any library function availabeis available to do this ?

Thanks in advance.